# Prism 4 and dotnet 3.5 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: prism-4

Will Prism 4 work in Visual Studio 2010 when compiling with .NET Framework 3.5?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work as it is solely for .NET 4/SL4:

- [David Hill](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/dphill/archive/2010/04/28/prism-4-0-have-your-say.aspx?Redirected=true)